# Error while loading shared libraries (libandroid.so): internal error

Tags: linux, arm, dynamic-linking, cross-compilation

I'm trying to run a sample sensor NDK application in an embedded target with Qualcomm Snapdragon QCS610 running a Linux BSP supplied from the dev board manufacturer. The sensor application depends on the prebuilt Android shared library (libandroid.so) that has to be copied to the target along with the executable. The problem is that I get an error while executing the binary on target: "Error while loading shared libraries: internal error".
While trying to identify the cause, I learnt that libandroid.so that the sensor application depends on is built for soft target (-mfloat-abi=soft).
The BSP libraries are built for armv7a with target FPU set as hard.
Assuming that the ABI compatibility of libandroid.so is the problem, is there an option for me to overcome this problem without rebuilding the BSP for soft target (-mfloat-abi=soft)?